# Preserve scalar dtype when bit shifting

Tags: numpy

I have a 32 bit uint scalar, how do i bit shift it without upcasting the dtype?

```
x = np.uint32(123456789)
x << 11
```

int64 Output:

```
252839503872
```

Expected output:

```
3731400704
```

It is possible to get my desired output by doing `np.uint32((x << 11) & 0xFFFFFFFF)`, but the syntax feels superfluous for such an easy operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both arguments have to have the desired dtype:

```
In [80]: np.left_shift(x,np.uint32(11))
Out[80]: 3731400704
In [81]: x<<np.uint32(11)
Out[81]: 3731400704
```

`x<<11` is an easy operation, but the `dtype` of the `np.array(11)` has control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.uint32(x << 11)` it'll will produce the expected output